# Save shop timing in elasticsearch

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I have a situation to save a shop timing in elastic-search. For example there is a shop have a timing like this

**Monday** :    7am-2pm , 4pm-8pm
**Tuesday** :   7am-2pm , 4pm-8pm
**Wednesday** :  7am-2pm , 4pm-8pm
**Thursday** :  7am-2pm , 4pm-8pm
**Friday** : 7am-2pm , 4pm-8pm
**Saturday** : 7am-2pm , 4pm-8pm
**Sunday** : closed

I have to save this timing and perform a search like which shop is open or which shop is closed.

For example If user searches on Monday at 7:04am The status of the shop is **OPEN** and if user searches at 2:10pm the status of the shop is **BREAK** and if user searches at 9:00pm the status is **CLOSED**. 
Any best approach how to find the status of the shop will help me.

Answer (score 0):

You may design your schema like :

```
{
  "day":"Monday"
  "slots"  : [
        {
        "startTime":420, //7*60 // MINUTE_OF_DAY (7am)
        "endTime":840,//12 + 2 * 60 //(2 pm)
        "type":"OPEN"
      },
      {
        "startTime":960, //16*60
        "endTime":1200,//20 * 60
        "type":"OPEN"

      },
      {
        "startTime":840, //14*60
        "endTime":960,//16 * 60
        "type":"BREAK"

      },
      {
        "startTime":1200, //20*60
        "endTime":1440, //24*60
        "type":"CLOSED"

      },
      {
        "startTime":0
        "endTime":420,
        "type":"CLOSED"

      },
  ]
}
```

Note : slots are of type "[nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-nested-type.html)"

Now, when you receive a query for day=Monday and time = 7:10 am, convert 7:10 am to minute of day i.e. 430
make a query like

```
where day=Monday AND slots.startTime < 430 AND slots.endTime>430
```

Use [inner_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html) to figure out the nested doc matching your criteria

Hope, it helps